# Best Way to Combine Twython and Scrapy?

Tags: python, twitter, twitter-oauth, scrapy

all!

So, I want to crawl Twitter using Twython. The problem is I kind of interested with Scrapy's feature too. If overwrite the `start_requests` with the Twython request function, wouldn't it be just a waste to use Scrapy at all? I heard Scrapy is fast, and I think it is because we use their `Request` function.

I mean, like this:

```
from twython import Twython

#Auth steps
AUTH = {"app_key": "xxx",
    "app_secret": "xxx",
    "oauth_token": "xxx",
    "oauth_token_secret": "xxx"}
twitter = Twython(**AUTH)    

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'myspider'

    def start_requests(self):
        return [twitter.lookup_user(user_id="259784090,136953436,1219150098")]
```

I am still confused why people choose Scrapy.

Thanks!
Ami